# What is the significance of Soubin Shahir's character in Carbon (2018)?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, carbon

*Rajesh*, Soubin Shahir's character as a mahout in the Malayalam film [Carbon (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(film)), appears first in the scene where *Sibi*, Fahadh Faasil's character, meets the elephant's owner. He was presented in the film as a character in *Sibi's* dream.  He reappears before the climax scene while in search of his elephant *Raghav*.

- What is the significance of *Rajesh* in this film?
- Was the second appearance of *Rajesh* also in *Sibi's* dream?

Comment: The first one was his dream and the second one was an illusion he sees as his lonely time in the forest. As he sees Mamtha mohandas's character